# Conversion of table to Excel from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, excel, gwt, extjs

I need to export my EditorGridPanel grid data to excel without sending any data to server-side, cross browser and cross platform solution that will work in ie6 and ie7.  **Any pure JavaScript solution is good as well!**
So far i have found only data URI solution which is great but ie supports it only from 8-th version. Also there is a possibility to export through ActiveX component but it is not what i want since it makes my app depended to Windows and MSOffice.

Can you recommend me any solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well after a wile of thinking i understood that this question is stupid because due to sandbox policy of js there is no possibility to export it directly from js.
As i said earlier i found some partial ways to do that:
ActiveX export  and  [Data URI scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data:_URI_scheme)

Answer (score 1):

You could export to csv and then import that file into Excel , Open Office or Numbers?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with a server-side call, but no server-side code writting.

http://code.google.com/p/gwt-table-to-excel/

Comment: nice tool, but i needed exactly xls :)

Answer (score 0):

The class below do that without server side.

```
public class TableToExcel {
    public static final <T> void save(final CellTable<T> table, String filename) {
        final AnchorElement a = Document.get().createAnchorElement();
        a.setHref("data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64," + base64(table.getElement().getString()));
        a.setPropertyString("download", (filename.endsWith(".xls") || filename.endsWith(".xlsx")) ? filename : filename + ".xls");

        Document.get().getBody().appendChild(a);
        Scheduler.get().scheduleEntry(new ScheduledCommand() {
            @Override
            public void execute() {
                click(a);
                a.removeFromParent();
            }
        });
    }

    private static native void click(Element elem) /*-{
        elem.click();
    }-*/;

    public static native String base64(String data) /*-{
        return btoa(data);
    }-*/;
}
```